# Is it possible to solve this second order differential equation by hand without using complex numbers

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to find a particular solution to the following differential equation: $y''+4y=\cos(2t)-2\sin(2t)$. I solved it using complex numbers, but I haven't been able to do it without complex numbers. I used the method of undetermined coefficients, which gave me the following solution (using real numbers): $y=(\frac{1}{t^2+1})\cos(2t)+\frac{t}{t^2+1}\sin(2t)$, but I don't think this is right. Is there any way to do this without complex numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions to
$$
y''+4y=0
$$
are
$$
y_h=C_1\cos 2t+C_2\sin 2t.
$$
To find a special solution to your equation, do the ansatz
$$
y_p=t(A\cos 2t+B\sin 2t).
$$
Insert the ansatz $y_p$ (all of it together!) into your differential equation and solve for $A$ and $B$.

Finally, your solutions to the differential equation are
$$
y=y_h+y_p.
$$

Comment: So I need to insert y= yh + yp into the equation, and not just yp?

Comment: No, just $y_p$. I updated. The reason I wrote as I did was that I got the impression that you looked at sine and cosine separately and not together...

Comment: Ok, turns out I was getting the wrong answer because I kept forgetting the 4y term.

Answer (score 1):

You can notice that this is the equation of a driven spring, with the driving frequency matching the natural spring frequency (because the solution to the homogeneous equation $y''+4y=0$ is $y = H \cos(2t+\delta)$.

A spring driven at its natural frequency would pick up a fixed amount of amplitude in each cycle, so it is natural to try solutions of the form
$$
y = (At+M)\cos(2t) + (Bt+N)\sin(2t)
$$
(in the end, $M$ and $N$ will be absorbed into the added solution to the homogeneuous equation).
$$
y' = -2(At+M)\sin(2t) +2(Bt+N)\cos(2t) + A \cos(2t) + B \sin(2t)$$
Then the equation becomes 
$$
y'' + 4y = -4(Ax+m) \cos(2t) + 4(Bx+N)\sin(2t) -2A\sin(2t) + 2B\cos(2t) -2A\sin(2t) + 2B\cos(2t) +4(Ax+m) \cos(2t) = 4(Bx+N)\sin(2t)  = -4A \sin(2t) +4B\cos(4t) = -2\sin(2t) + \cos(2t)
$$
so 
$$A=\frac{1}{2} \\
B = \frac{1}{4}
$$
and the general solution is 
$$
y = \left( \frac{t}{2}+M \right) \cos(2t) + \left( \frac{t}{2}+N \right) \sin(2t)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: assume $$y_p=C_1tcos(2t)+C_2tsin(2t)$$

Comment: Multiply that ansatz by $t$.

Comment: I did exactly that. Also, I found y1 for cos(2t) and y2 for -2sin(2t) separately. Then I put y = y1 + y2.

Comment: @mickep thanks for your attention